# How do I return a list of users if I use the Firebase simple username & password authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Not sure if I am doing something wrong but using this api https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html I can successfully create a user - according to the return message, but I can not see that user anywhere in the Forge console.  How do you know what users are registered?

Should I be taking the return user ID and creating my own user object in Firebase or is this duplication unnecessary.  I do need to add some additional user properties so perhapes I will need to do this anyway.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

When using email / password authentication in Firebase Authentication (previously known as Firebase SimpleLogin), your user's email and password combination is securely stored separately from the data actually stored in your Firebase.

This barrier between the data in your Firebase and your users' email / password hash combinations is by design: we want to make it easier for you to (1) develop your application, (2) prevent any accidental user credential leaks, and (3) still give you total flexibility with how to store your user data in Firebase.

That means that we only store the email address / password hash combination and nothing else, so it is up to you to decide how to store actual user data in your Firebase. As you suggested, you should be taking the user id and storing that data in your Firebase in a location such as /users/$id, and using the Firebase [Security Rules Language](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/security-rules.html) to determine read / write access to that data. Your user's unique `id` and `email` are already in the `auth` variable you'll use when writing rules.

Comment: Thanks for the information - I assume there is a dependency there though, if the data I store per user goes out of synch, say accidentally deleted, how would I know who could currently access my application?  Its good that the data is separate but surely thats negated by the fact I can't see it from an administration POV?

Comment: There used to be a list of users (without passwords) in the Firebase console, with the ability to delete them, but it is gone now. Any chance that will be added back?

Comment: We will be adding this back at some point, but I don't have a concrete timeline yet. I'll follow-up here once we've made progress on this - thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Listing all created users and deleting users looks like a must have!

Comment: @g108 The deletion and listing of user accounts created with Firebase Simple Login has been enabled once again in Forge, and will list the email / password-hash mappings as well as allow you to delete those mappings. Keep in mind that it is very barebones, and we intend to completely re-work it once we have resources to do so.

Comment: The user list accessible via console is now back in the new Google's Firebase

Comment: @joaquin The user list was great on console of Firebase; until some kind of update affected the search of all authenticated users. It was really easy to search by typing in search field '@' character to see all authenticated user. Unfortunately Firebase is now only allowed to search by email or uid. Is there a way to find all authenticated users without using BigQuery.

Comment: 1. Can we return the list of users though if they signed up using facebook auth? 

2. For users that have already signed up and weren't saved in the database at the time of registration (assuming the above can't be done) how do we export and then import them into the database

Comment: @robertmylne You can either access the user list directly into the console, or export the entire list using the Firebase CLI. *See* 'auth:export' on https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth and decide what to do with the user list from there.

Comment: This is a must have... Kinda defeats the purpose of a user database if the admin SDK can't transverse the users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Frank. However, if the separate user database that you are talking about only stores email/password combinations (not any other user info), why under the Manager Users section (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) do they mention the `user.updateProfile` method with the ability to save a `displayName` and `photoURL`? Where does this info get stored then? It's not saving in my Firestore - I checked - so I'm assuming it is in that separate DB. What's the point of this method if the current user is the only one who can see it?

Comment: so lets say in the app admins can delete users from database in this case their authentication will still exist, how can you solve this case ?

Answer (score 11):

Here i created an Android program to do what Rob said for firebase beginner(like me)
out there.this program first store the username of the signedUp or signedIn user and then display them in a listView

**SignInActivity.java**

```
public class SignInActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener,View.OnKeyListener{

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    public static FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    EditText usernameField;
    EditText passwordField;
    TextView changeSignUpModeTextView;
    Button signUpButton;
    ImageView logo;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    Boolean signUpModeActive;
    static ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Check auth on Activity start
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            onAuthSuccess(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

        if(i == keyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            signUpOrLogIn(view);
        }
         return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(view.getId() == R.id.changeSignUpMode){

            if (signUpModeActive == true){

                signUpModeActive = false;
                changeSignUpModeTextView.setText("Sign Up");
                signUpButton.setText("Log In");

            }else{

                signUpModeActive = true;
                changeSignUpModeTextView.setText("Log In");
                signUpButton.setText("Sign Up");
            }

        }else if(view.getId() == R.id.logo || view.getId() == R.id.relativeLayout){

            InputMethodManager inm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),0);

        }

    }


    public void signUpOrLogIn(View view) {

        showProgressDialog();
        String email = usernameField.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = passwordField.getText().toString().trim();

        if (signUpModeActive == true) {
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            hideProgressDialog();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException().toString().substring(task.getException().toString().indexOf(" ")),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.i("Error", task.getException().toString());
                            } else {
                                onAuthSuccess(task.getResult().getUser());
                                showUserList();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            hideProgressDialog();
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // there was an error

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, task.getException().toString(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else

                            {
                                onAuthSuccess(task.getResult().getUser());
                                showUserList();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    public void showUserList(){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserList.class));
        finish();
    }
    private void onAuthSuccess(FirebaseUser user) {
        String username = usernameFromEmail(user.getEmail());

        // Write new user
        writeNewUser(user.getUid(), username, user.getEmail());

        // Go to MainActivity

    }
    private String usernameFromEmail(String email) {
        if (email.contains("@")) {
            return email.split("@")[0];
        } else {
            return email;
        }
    }

    private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
        User user = new User(name, email);

        mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
        ArrayList<String> userNames = new ArrayList<>();
        userNames.add(name);
        mDatabase.child("usernamelist").setValue(userNames);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
            showUserList();
        }

        usernameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        changeSignUpModeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changeSignUpMode);
        signUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupbutton);
        logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo);
        relativeLayout= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        signUpModeActive = true;

        changeSignUpModeTextView.setOnClickListener(this);

        usernameField.setOnKeyListener(this);
        passwordField.setOnKeyListener(this);

        logo.setOnClickListener(this);
        relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);



    }
}
```

**UserList.java**

```
public class UserList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "UserList" ;
    private DatabaseReference userlistReference;
    private ValueEventListener mUserListListener;
    ArrayList<String> usernamelist = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;;

    ListView userListView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list);
        userlistReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("usernamelist");
        onStart();
        userListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userlistview);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final ValueEventListener userListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                usernamelist = new ArrayList<>((ArrayList) dataSnapshot.getValue());
                usernamelist.remove(usernameOfCurrentUser());
                Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: "+usernamelist.toString());
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(UserList.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,usernamelist);
                userListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled: ",databaseError.toException());
                Toast.makeText(UserList.this, "Failed to load User list.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        userlistReference.addValueEventListener(userListener);

        mUserListListener = userListener;
    }
    public String usernameOfCurrentUser()
    {
        String email = MainActivity.mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        if (email.contains("@")) {
            return email.split("@")[0];
        } else {
            return email;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // Remove post value event listener
        if (mUserListListener != null) {
            userlistReference.removeEventListener(mUserListListener);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_logout:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to use cloud function to fetch users list (view docs at [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users)). Note, in the following example [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) feature is used to check if user has enough privileges.

```
// USERS: return full users list for admin
// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

export const listUsers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // check if user is admin (true "admin" custom claim), return error if not
  const isAdmin = context.auth.token.admin === true
  if (!isAdmin) {
    return { error: `Unauthorized.` }
  }

  return admin
    .auth()
    .listUsers()
    .then((listUsersResult) => {
      // go through users array, and deconstruct user objects down to required fields
      const result = listUsersResult.users.map((user) => {
        const { uid, email, photoURL, displayName, disabled } = user
        return { uid, email, photoURL, displayName, disabled }
      })

      return { result }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return { error: 'Error listing users' }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Google Identity Toolkit API](http://google.github.io/google-api-nodejs-client/19.0.0/identitytoolkit.html#.identitytoolkit.relyingparty.downloadAccount__anchor) to get a list of all registered users in your Firebase project, this API is used by the [Firebase CLI](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/lib/accountExporter.js#L129) which can be accessed by running `firebase auth:export results-file`

Make sure Identity Toolkit API is enabled

**firebase-users-list.js**

```
const serviceAccount = require('path/to/firebase-sdk-json-service-account');

const googleapis = require('googleapis');
const identitytoolkit = googleapis.identitytoolkit('v3');

const authClient = new googleapis.auth.JWT(
    serviceAccount.client_email,
    null,
    serviceAccount.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase'],
    null
);

authClient.authorize((err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }

    let nextPageToken = undefined;
    let users = [];
    const getAccounts = () => identitytoolkit.relyingparty.downloadAccount({
        auth: authClient,
        resource: {
            targetProjectId: serviceAccount.project_id,
            maxResults: 200,
            nextPageToken: nextPageToken
        }
    }, (e, results) => {
        if (e) {
            return console.error(err);
        }

        users = users.concat(results.users);
        if (results.nextPageToken) {
            nextPageToken = results.nextPageToken;
            return getAccounts();
        } else {
            console.log(users);
        }
    });
    getAccounts();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using `admin.auth().listUsers`

Here is the doc for this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#listusers

And an usage example: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users

```
function listAllUsers(nextPageToken) {
  // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
  admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
        console.log('user', userRecord.toJSON());
      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Error listing users:', error);
    });
}
// Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.
listAllUsers();
```

Comment: Admin lib should not be used on client side?

Comment: Yes admin is only for server side (security reasons). But you may do an intermediate API if you need informations on client side.

Comment: yes, an intermediate api was the correct way to go, but requires setup, etc. An alternate way I though might be useful was, while creating the user, I'd also save the details i need which is (username) in another :root/[list-users]/[user], then have firebase rules set to 'only logged in users' for this ref.

Comment: Good idea. Firestore still not allows to store user information inside users (which i find stupid :D ) So you will need to create a user list in firestore at one time ^^

Comment: Note if you don't want to create an "API" you can still rely on firebase "functions"

Comment: but if you use firebase "functions", you still have to authenticate requests (using something like jwt) right? or is there any way around it (it should be secure)? BTW im using realtime database, not firestore.

Answer (score 1):

i will answer it simply as much as possible 
just add the registered user to your data base by using the following code

you can also use shared prefernces to save  the data locally but it won't be able for other user.

once you save the list of user in the database simply retrieve it from there using adapters

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("my_user")
                        .child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid())
                        .child("username").setValue(autoCompleteTextView1.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Users list in python:**

```py
from firebase_admin import credentials, db, auth
cred = credentials.Certificate('\path\to\serviceAccountKey.json')
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    "databaseURL": "https://data_base_url.firebaseio.com"
})
users = auth.list_users()
```