# Firebase AngularJS full data access

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm building an app based on Firebase + AngularJS. I'm using User management service by Firebase. I'm able to get all data for Authenticated user, however, I'm not able to retrieve all user data as admin. How can I get full access to Firebase data.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are looking to [return a list of users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708). Also have a look at the [Firebase documentation on storing user data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing)

Answer (score 0):

As Frank mentioned in the comment, Firebase doesn't make user account information available to the admin. Rather, some information is available on the client after authentication and it could be sent to be stored as explicit data in Firebase.
The [link Frank provide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing) in the comment explains how to do this.

> Applications do not automatically store profile or user state. To persist user data you must save it to your database. The callback function will return an object containing the data for the authenticated user, which you can then write to your database.

Here is the core of the example

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData && isNewUser) {
  // save the user's profile into the database so we can list users,
  // use them in Security and Firebase Rules, and show profiles
  ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).set({
   provider: authData.provider,
   name: getName(authData)
  });
 }
});
```