# Get a list of all users in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been working in a project which involves firebase as backend and Angulars, I am currently facing the way to return a list with all my firebase users. I can see there is only information in the documentation about [**currentUser**] https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users but I need to return all users and manage them, update password and email and delete accounts.

My old method worked absolutely fine, but as all know firebase has change their way to code the methods, this is my old method:

```
$scope.ChangePass = function() {

    var email = $scope.data.email;
    var passwordChanged = $scope.data.password;
    var newPasswordChanged = $scope.data.newPassword;

    var ref = new Firebase("https://myfirebaseapp.firebaseio.com/");
    ref.changePassword({
        email: email,
        oldPassword: passwordChanged,
        newPassword: newPasswordChanged

    }, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            switch (error.code) {
                case "INVALID_PASSWORD":
                    console.log("The specified user account password is incorrect.");
                    break;
                case "INVALID_USER":
                    console.log("The specified user account does not exist.");
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Error changing password:", error);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("User password changed successfully!");
        }
    });
```

And this is the new way according to firebase, but the issue is that it only captures the current user.

```
 $scope.ChagePassword = function(){
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var newPassword = $scope.newpass.newPassword;
        user.updatePassword(newPassword).then(function() {

            console.log('password account changed successfully');

        }, function(error) { console.log(error);

            console.log('password account change failure');// An error happened.
        });
    }//END FUNCTION
```

Is there any way to do this possible? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as I know you will need to first signIn and then change your password or whatever.

Comment: what do you need to do with the users? need to edit them or only display? also: how are your security rules within firebase?

Comment: I need to be able to update them or delete them, but as first step I need to display them.

Comment: There is no administrative API for managing Firebase Authentication users at the moment. For getting a list of users, most developers end up storing that list in the Firebase Database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password

Comment: Firebase used to be cool! Thanks anyway!