# Retrieve list of user from Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How can I retrieve the list of users from Firebase Authentication? I can get the 'current' user but that's it. Or do I have to add users to database first and get the list from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to retrieve a list of users from Firebase Authentication.

The explanation is in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password)

The only way to do that is to save the user to the database once they are registered.

Comment: Now you can, by calling [.listUsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939765/retrieving-a-list-of-users-who-have-registered-using-firebase-auth/46947495#46947495) in the Admin SDK.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a nodejs project, use the `firebase auth:export` to export users from Firebase Auth. Users can be exported in csv or json format:

```
firebase auth:export users.json --format=json --project projectname
```