# How can i get all users from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication. I can see 250 users from firebase panel. But i want to see all users. I didn't use realtime database to keep user informations. Is there any way to see more than 250 users? Or how can i move current users to realtime database?

Comment: You want to see *all* users? Isn't the 250 users *all* the users there are?

Comment: @Rexford no, if there are more than 250 i can see last 250 users only. For example if i have 400 users. I can see last 250 users. I cant see 150 users.

Comment: There is no API to get a list of users from Firebase Authentication. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757121/retrive-list-of-user-from-firebase-authentication

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your answer.