# Retrieving a list of users who have registered using Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making an android chat application using firebase. So far I have made a common group chat app. Now I want to make it an individual chat app, which will have a Users list and when we select a person from that list we can chat individually with him/her. However I am not able to get this Users list from Firebase. I have kept Google Sign in and Email sign in options in the Firebase Auth UI. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think there are two ways. The first way is to save the UIDs of the users in the database, and render your list using that UID. In that way, you know what the UID is when a user clicks on it. Another way is to retrieve UID using a username, display name or any attribute. However, that must use server auth. You need to set up a node server and retrieve user information using API (remember to trim off sensitive information in your server).

Answer (score 10):

The Firebase Admin SDK allows retrieving the entire list of users in batches:

```
function listAllUsers(nextPageToken) {
  // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
  admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
        console.log('user', userRecord.toJSON());
      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Error listing users:', error);
    });
}
// Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.
listAllUsers();
```

Note: This API is currently only available for the Admin Node.js SDK.

via https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Answer (score 8):

If you need to lookup users by `uid`, `email` or `phoneNumber`, you can use the Admin SDK to do so:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

You also even have the ability to download all your users:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users

You would need to do that from a Node.js backend server or via HTTP endpoints with Firebase Functions.

In addition the Admin SDK allows you to set custom user attributes which could be helpful if you want to create different user groups:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

`admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {groupId: '1234'})`

Answer (score 3):

```
const allUsers: firebase.auth.UserRecord[] = [];

const listAllUsers = async (nextPageToken?: string) => {
  const res = await firebase.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken);
  allUsers.push(...res.users);
  if (res.pageToken) {
    await listAllUsers(res.pageToken);
  }
};

await listAllUsers();

console.log(allUsers)
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Sam earlier, you can fetch details from Firebase DB. So every time a user signs up, add his FirebaseUser details (preferably his UID, under which you store his other details if required) to the DB. Then simply put a listener on the Database in your next activity, and you can fetch a list of all registered users.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve the data of all authenticated user from Firebase Authentication, however you can only get the current user.

In Order to get the data of registered user you need to store it into database and then retrieve the whole array, or you can just keep the authentication flag which can be set or reset if the user is registered in your all-user table and vice versa.

As mentioned by @Jason you can try Admin SDK as it is mentioned in the documentation that listAllUsers() can retrieve batch of user data.

The detailed explanation can be found [IN THIS THREAD.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password)

Comment: With admin SDK you can. see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Answer (score -3):

If you want to view a list of users that has registered thru Firebase Auth, you may view them in `https://console.firebase.google.com/` then go to your project and select `authentication`, in the `Users` list is all the users that have registered thru Firebase Auth.

Comment: That does not even remotely come close to what the question is.