# how to get all users ID's from firebase auth in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am a beginner at flutter, In my project I need to get then list every Authenticated user's **id** from **Firebase Auth** not from Firestore. Is that possible?

Comment: I think this might be what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939765/retrieving-a-list-of-users-who-have-registered-using-firebase-auth

Answer (score 0):

firebase will assign uid to every authentication, so you can get the user id by

```
firebaseAuth.currentuser.uid
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you FirebaseAuth like this
**FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid** for more visit
[firebase auth](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage)