# FirebaseAuth Java is only android applications?

Tags: java, firebase-authentication

I would like to use firebaseAuth as my authenticator api.

I created user, but there is no possibility to login with email and password.
I found an endpoint to access and login, but I wish there was a method in Firebase Auth to do that.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of Firebase SDKs (including those for Java):

1. SDKs for use in untrusted clients, which are integrated into the app/site your users access. The Firebase Authentication SDK for Android is an example of this, and it allows the user to sign in to Firebase with many providers, including email+password.
2. Admin SDKs for use in trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. These Admin SDKs access the Firebase project with administrative privileges (hence their name), meaning that they have full access to the entire project. These SDKs, including the Firebase Authentication Admin SDK for Java, do not have a way to sign in to Firebase (as they're already authorized to access all resources), but do for example allow you [verify ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), [create, update, and delete user profiles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user), and many more actions.

The Admin SDKs cannot be used from client-side application code, so you will have to find a way to fit your use-case into one of the SDKs, or use a combination of both SDK types, by setting up a custom API that your client-side application code calls into.

Also see:

- [Retrieving a list of users who have registered using Firebase Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939765/retrieving-a-list-of-users-who-have-registered-using-firebase-auth/46947495#46947495)

Comment: Thank you Frank! I got you!
In my case I needed to check firebase to validate and create my api token.
I saw a solution when the client passes firebase auth token, I can check this token and create my own token to access apis.