# How to fetch a list of 'FirebaseUser' programatically?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to fetch a list of 'FirebaseUser' created by Password Based Authentication, programatically?

This is my use case:

I have an app which handles 'Managers'(or Admins) as well as 'Users'(normal employees). The managers must be able to create, query and delete other users.

Do Firebase provide any such administrator APIs?

Comment: There is no API in Firebase Authentication to retrieve a list of users. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357994/how-to-fetch-a-list-of-firebaseuser-programatically and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password

Comment: It seems like Firebase introduced Admin Apis 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users