# Fetch all users from Firebase with Facebook login - swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app is using Facebook login only at the moment. I am trying to build a search function using the `UISearchBar`.

So my question is: Is it in any way possible to fetch all users from the Firebase database into an array? Maybe even get their `UserID` as well??

If you want to see any piece of code let me know, I just did not think it was relevant to this question :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return a list of users if I use the Firebase simple username & password authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password)

Comment: @HamzaAnsari: while that question was about email+password users and this one is about social providers, the answer is indeed the same. There is no API to list the users in Firebase Authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood what you're trying to achieve then you should simply be able to save your users to the Realtime database upon registering/authenitcating your users.

After this you can perform a simple observeSingleEventOf to get all your users at the correct path, something like this:

```
rootRef.usersRef.observeSingleEvent(ofType: .value).....
```

Then with the completion handler you should get back a snapshot, the snapshot.value will include all your users.

*Please note that you don't need to stop observing this method since it will observe the values once then immediately stop. So I don't think you need to worry about memory issues.