# Firebase user not save to database when registering

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am registering users in my app, the registration works in the app but when i check my databse the records are not saved, as in the database is empty, but the app says user registered and it also redirects me to the next activity which is profile.activity. Where exactly is my data sent?? i dont see it in my database

Here is my code.
    private void registerUser(){

```
        //getting email and password from edit texts
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        //checking if email and passwords are empty
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        //if the email and password are not empty
        //displaying a progress dialog

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

        //creating a new user
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //checking if success
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                        }else{
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    }
```

Comment: @UmarAta i used a different code it works fine but i do not see any records in my databse??

Comment: try to send message after registering new users then check the new records get created or not

Answer (score 3):

The user information that Firebase collects and stores for you when you create a new user using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is not stored within your Firebase Database. Instead, it's stored a user database. If you want to know a little more about what exactly is stored and how to access that data, there's information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users).

Your Firebase Database is what you see when you click on the Firebase tab:
[image]

And your User Database you can see when you click on the Authentication tab:

[image]

So if you want to see your new users popping up, just head over to the Authentication tab. If you need to associate data with your users beyond what Firebase stores automatically, you can save that data in your Firebase Database, usually using the unique user ID that Firebase generates as the key.

Comment: Great answer. For more info on how to store the users in the database, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password