# Getting other users' profile information on firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase Database for my Android app. For each user I want to display other users' emails in a list view like in whatsapp. FirebaseUser only lets me get the current user while I want other users too. Is there a way to get other users?

Comment: Is sounds like your uses are signing in with Firebase Authentication. There is no API in Firebase Authentication to get a list of users. The idiomatic way to get such functionality is to keep a list of users in the Firebase Database. See this answer for more on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password

Answer (score -1):

B

Yeah there is a way to get the other users too.
You can have a node in your users Section of the tree that has a list of all other users they can contact or see.

```
           yourDatabaseReferance.child(UID).push().child("UIDS_I_WANT_TO_SEE")
.setValue(otherUID);
```

Then you can pull them down into a Strings Array List and use that to directly connect to that users information in your database structure, for example pulling the email information like you want.