# Firebase query to get users email registered with social login (js)

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, get

What is on Firebase the query to get users email if they signed up using social login?

I'm using javascript, i know how to access database etc. but i'm not personally saving users email address, firebase does that automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no client-side API to get a listing of users, as that would make it very easy to leak information about your users.

If you want to expose this information, you have two common options:

1. Store the information you want to expose in a database (such as the Firebase Realtime Database, or Cloud Firestore), and then access *that* from the app.
2. Create an endpoint (for example through Cloud Functions) that uses the Admin SDK to return a list of users.

Neither is pertinently better in all situations, although I believe the first one is a lot more commonly used.

Also see:

- [How do I return a list of users if I use the Firebase simple username & password authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password) (back from before Firebase had an Admin SDK that contains functionality to list users)
- [Retrieving a list of users who have registered using Firebase Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939765/retrieving-a-list-of-users-who-have-registered-using-firebase-auth?rq=1) (more recent, and mentions the Admin SDK in an answer by one of its authors)
- [How can I list all users using firebase admin sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011844/how-can-i-list-all-users-using-firebase-admin-sdk)