# Flutter : Get all registered firebase users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

I use Google sign in to authenticated users in my flutter app, and i want to get all the registered users, but i don't know how to get all the users. Do we have a method that allow to get the users?

Comment: There is no way to get all users from the Firebase Authentication SDK for Flutter/Android. The typical way to deal with this is to keep a list of all users in the database (either Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore), or nowadays to create a Cloud Functions endpoint that uses the Admin SDK to expose this data. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14673708, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46939765, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41012644/209103

Comment: ok, my alternative is to save their infos when logged in