# Get all registered users in firebase in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Is there any possibility to get all users from Firebase from Flutter app?
If not, then is it good practice to store user data (email, display name, phone, image url) in Firebase database?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+get+all+users, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53373930/flutter-get-all-registered-firebase-users

Answer (score 2):

You can get all your users if you are using the Firebase admin SDK. You cannot get them all if you are using a Flutter app because the Flutter app doesn't use the Firebase admin sdk.

You can get all you users using the Firebase admin sdk and then through an api, send the information to your Flutter app for display.

Yes, of course. It is not a bad practice at all to store user data (except passwords) in Firebase database