# Add profile picture to firebase while also showing it to other users

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have a Kotlin app where I want to add a profile picture on my profile page but I also want to make a list for an admin account where he can see names/email and profile pictures.

I have seen old questions where they where storing it firestore and not firebase-auth that seems inefficient because I am making calls for both. Should I store all user data in the database or are there better ways to do this while still being able to have an admin page.

Here is some relevant code to show the structure of my project.
I have other functions but they seem irrelevant.

```
class AuthViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val auth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private val authEventsChannel = Channel<AuthEvent>()
    val authEvents = authEventsChannel.receiveAsFlow()
    private val db = Firebase.firestore

    val currentUser
        get() = auth.currentUser

    fun uploadProfileImage(it: Uri) {}
```

And here the frontend

```
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    val authViewModel: AuthViewModel = viewModel()
    val currentUser = authViewModel.currentUser
    var showImagePicker by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val profileImageUri = remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }

    val imagePickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
    ) { uri: Uri? ->
        uri?.let {
            profileImageUri.value = it
            authViewModel.uploadProfileImage(it)
        }
    }

Button(onClick = {
            showImagePicker = true
        }) {
            Text("Change Profile Picture")
        }
        profileImageUri.value?.let { uri ->
            Image(
                painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(uri),
                contentDescription = "Profile Picture",
                modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp)
            )
        }
```

Comment: "that seems unefficient" You might want to clarify why that seems inefficient to you, given that's been the idiomatic approach to implement this use-case for years.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated my question to explain my reasoning. I also tried to search for official documentation but could not find that, since this is the default way to do it is there official documentation?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "official" way to list users in your app.

The Firebase Admin SDKs have an [API to list all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users), but those cannot be used directly from the client and are not focused on performance for this type of use-case.

The common way to implement this use-case is to load the current user's profile from Firebase Auth, and information about other user's data from another data source.

Also see:

- [Firebase list all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67903927/firebase-list-all-users)
- [How can I list all users using firebase admin sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011844/how-can-i-list-all-users-using-firebase-admin-sdk)
- [How do I return a list of users if I use the Firebase simple username & password authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password)