# Access Firebase user UID by email address from Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase

Firebase offers a NodeJS SDK to perform User Management. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

I need to access user data (e.g UID) by email address from a Java server environment. Unfortunately, Firebase does not offer a Java implementation of the NodeJS SDK.

Is there an alternative to access a users Firebase UID by email address from a Java server environment (App Engine)?

Comment: There is indeed no Java version of the Authentication APIs for Admin SDK. This means that you'll have to implement an alternative way of mapping email addresses to UID, such as keeping a `/users` node in a Firebase Database as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password (and probably many of these too: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+users+list)

Comment: Thanks Frank! I know I can make a mapping by myself but I prefer not to. Since I know you're a Firebase engineer: do you expect to release a Java version of the Authentication APIs for Admin SDK?

Comment: We're aware that it would be useful to have this functionality available in the Java Admin SDK too. But we have nothing to announce at this time. I've relayed your request to the relevant team however. If you want, you can also do that yourself directly through our [feature request page](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). As it stands now, I don't think anyone on Stack Overflow is likely to be able to help though.

Comment: Great Frank, thanks for your answer. I've relayed the request as per your suggestion. For now, I will manage the mapping myself in the App Engine DataStore (the Java service I'm running is an App Engine Service).