# How to list the email users from Auth in Angularfire - firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm trying to create a backend for my app which use firebase.

For this I decided to go with Angular + Angularfire - which is looking good !

I've added the possibility to create user from the back end via:

```
var app =  angular
.module('app', ['firebase'])
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
function($firebaseAuth) {
return $firebaseAuth();
  }
     ]);

app.controller("SampleCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth",
function($scope, Auth) {
$scope.createUser = function() {
  $scope.message = "One or more field is not correctly entered !";
  $scope.error = null;

  // Create a new user
  Auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.email, $scope.password)
    .then(function(firebaseUser) {
      $scope.message = "User created with email: " + $scope.email + " and ID " + firebaseUser.uid;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      $scope.error = error;
    });
};

$scope.deleteUser = function() {
  $scope.message = null;
  $scope.error = null;

  Auth.$deleteUser().then(function() {
    $scope.message = "User deleted";
  }).catch(function(error) {
    $scope.error = error;
  });
   };
 }
   ]);
```

and

```
  <div ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
  Email: <input type="text" ng-model="email">
  Password: <input type="password" ng-model="password">

 <br><br>

<button ng-click="createUser()">Create User</button>

<br><br>

<button ng-click="deleteUser()">Delete User</button>

<p ng-if="message">Message: <strong>{{ message }}</strong></p>
<p ng-if="error">Error: <strong>{{ error }}</strong></p>
</div>
```

Which create user in my firebase Authentification perfectly.

I'd like somehow to be able to list all the emails of those uses,

How is this possible ?

I've been reading multiple thread and trying this:

```
  <ul><li ng-repeat='user in users'>{{user.name}}</li></ul>
```

without any success ...

Anybody get some idea ?

Will be awesome, thanks !

Comment: There is no public API in Firebase Authentication to get a list of users. Most developers implement such functionality by storing a list of user profiles in their Firebase Database. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14673708 and some of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+list+of+users

Comment: make all sense, i was not sur about it ! Thanks ;)

Comment: How can I store the userid when user register via the code I've listed on the post in the database ? I cant make it work :(

Comment: There should be quite some example of that our there. If you're having trouble making them work, open a question showing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).