# AngularFire Get users list

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to get list of users from my firebase, but my getUsers method returns undefined. Why this happens and what is correct way to get users array from "Authentificated" section?

[image]

What I tried to do:

provider-

```
export class FirebaseProvider {

  constructor(private afdatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getUsers() {
    return this.afdatabase.list('/users');
  }
}
```

users.ts -

```
export class UsersPage {

  usersList: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>

  constructor(private firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider) {

    this.usersList = this.firebaseProvider.getUsers()

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you need to create users in database section, cuz firebase won't let you to fetch users list from "authentificated" section for security reasons.

See:
[How do I return a list of users if I use the Firebase simple username & password authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password)