# Get User Email From Uid Without Login to app Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created a Firebase app.

Is there any way to get user email by `Uid` Without login to the app?

Answer (score 2):

No the user has to be logged in to be able to retrieve his information based on the `userid`

To get the uid, you need to do this:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userid=user.getUid();
```

According to the docs:

> `public FirebaseUser getCurrentUser ()`
>
> Returns the currently signed-in FirebaseUser or null if there is none.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible, you can use [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). You can write a cloud function which will return user mail by UID param :) No firebase authentication required, simple and awesome. Here is a short example:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
exports.getUserMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, resp) => {
    admin.auth().getUser(req.query.uid)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without logging in. Your email address and password are stored separately from the user data for security reasons. See below:

[How do I return a list of users if I use the Firebase simple username & password authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Firebase Admin SDK. You can lookup a user by uid, email or phone number:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    console.log(userRecord.email);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
  });
```