# How can I retrieve the list of all the registered users on Firebase Authentication service?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am pretty new with Angular and Firebase and I have the following problem but I am not finding a solution searching online so I am not sure that what I want to do is possible.

In my application I am handling user registration using Angular Authentication (via Gmail and user\password registration).

I need to know how can I retrieve the list of all registered users from my Angular code. Is it possible?

Reading here it seems that it is not possible: [How do I return a list of users if I use the Firebase simple username & password authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password)

But I don't need all the users information: I only need the name and the Google picture (if present). Is this possible?

Comment: Getting a list of users is getting a list of users, even if you just need their name and profile picture. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+get+list+of+users. Many of these point to the two main options: 1) store user info in a database that you can query, 2) create an custom API endpoint where you use a Firebase Admin SDK to retrieve the list of users. Note that #1 is by far the more common option, as you'll often want to store more information about a user anyway than Firebase Authentication allows.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible using the APIs provided for web and mobile clients, including Angular.

You can use the Firebase Admin SDK on your backend to [list users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).  You could also use a database to store information each user after they sign up, and query that database from your web client.

Comment: At the moment I am not planning to have a true backend...can I do it using a Cloud Function to retrieve the name and image of the new registered user?

Comment: Cloud Functions is a true backend.  You can use the Admin SDK with that.

Comment: Something like this?

Comment: What are you referring to?